# How to resolve spark exception no such method error in structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

```
 SparkSession sparkSession=SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("myApp")
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();
    
    
    Dataset<Row> lines = sparkSession.readStream()         
    .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
    .option("topic","uzumaki")
    .load("tcp://localhost:1883");

StreamingQuery query = lines.writeStream()
    .outputMode("complete")
    .format("console")
    .start();
   
   query.awaitTermination();
```

This is the code im getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Class org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(java.lang.String)'` also im using latest version of spark 3.4.0